# Can I pass additional parameters to the insert/update/delete SPs that are mapped to an entity?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I have an entity model in Entity Framework 5 and I want to use existing stored procedures for the insert/update/delete operations. I know how to map these SPs to my entities, but the SPs require additional status parameters (mainly used for logging purposes). These status parameters are not properties of any entity, so I have no way to map these parameters in the Mapping designer.

Is there any way to ‘plug in’ some custom code, so that I can use these stored procs for the insert/update/delete operations on my entities, and still call the stored procedures with these extra parameters?

Comment: Apologies if this has been asked/answered before, but it is hard to search for this specific scenario. Usually the only results that pop up simply describe how to map stored procedures to entities / model functions the regular way.

Comment: Daan, please have a look EF's `ExecuteStoreCommand`. It should help you to pass params to an underlying sp

Comment: @ChintanaMeegamarachchi I may be missing something, but how would I use `ExecuteStoreCommand` and still be able to bind the stored procs to the entities, so that the stored procs are used by default when saving changes to the entities? I can understand how to use the `ExecuteStoreCommand` (or the designer-supported way of mapping stored procedures to model functions) to create 'stand-alone' functions, but I want to bind them to the entities as the default way of inserting/deleting/updating them (i.e. without explicitly calling a model function).

Comment: Yes Daan, you are correct, it would not work in that case