# Parameters are not passed to SQL Stored Procedure mapped as Delete function

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, stored-procedures, entity-framework-6

I am new to Entity Framework 6. I want SQL Stored Procedure mapped as 'Delete' function to use parameters passed during execution of deleting record. 
When I do 'Delete' operation I need to do extra cleanup on the database and for this purpose I need additional parameters in 'Delete' Stored Procedure.

I pass 4 parameters: ID of the entity to be deleted, 
FK to parent entity (Although not needed by me, but requested by EF 6. See http://pamelayang.blogspot.com/2009/07/entity-framework-error-2048-when-using.html). These 2 first parameters work as expected. Next I pass 2 additional parameters which should contain values of modified fields of the record previosuly loaded into C# memory.

While looking in SQL Profiler 2 first parameters (PK and FK) are passed correctly into the Stored Procedure, but the 2 additional parameters have old values. When I skip step 5) in the below example (`DBSet.Remove(parcel);`) then during execution of `DBContainer.SaveChanges();` Stored Procedure mapped as an 'Update' operation is executed and these 2 extra parameters have correct NEW values. But during 'Delete' operation these 2 extra parameters contain wrong, old values.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create Stored Procedure that takes 4 parameters.

   ```
   CREATE PROCEDURE ParcelDeleteFomSDE (@Id int, @RightOfWayProject_Id int, @NextDate DateTime2, @Login nvarchar(max))
   ```
2. Map this procedurę as Delete function in EDMX (or using Visual Studio EDMX designer):

   ```
   <DeleteFunction FunctionName="ELSCE.Store.ParcelDeleteFomSDE>
     <ScalarProperty Name="Id" ParameterName="Id" />
     <AssociationEnd AssociationSet="RightOfWayProjectParcel" From="Parcel" To="RightOfWayProject"><ScalarProperty Name="Id" ParameterName="RightOfWayProject_Id" />
     </AssociationEnd>
   <ScalarProperty Name="NextDate" ParameterName="NextDate" />
    <ScalarProperty Name="Login" ParameterName="Login" />
    </DeleteFunction>
   ```
3. In C# code load record from the database:

   ```
   Parcel parcel= DBSet.Find(ID);
   ```
4. Modify two fields of this record:

   ```
   parcel.NextDate="2014-01-16";
   parcel.Login="StackOverflow Login";
   ```
5. Delete this record:

   ```
   DBSet.Remove(parcel);
   ```
6. Run save to the database:

   ```
   DBContainer.SaveChanges();
   ```
7. And now stored procedure ParcelDeleteFomSDE is executed but the problem is that @NextDate and @Login contain **old values** - i.e. modifications done in step 4) are ignored!

Is this a bug in EF6 or the fact of ignoring new values is by design?

I have found similar topic here:
[Can I pass additional parameters to the insert/update/delete SPs that are mapped to an entity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14624572/can-i-pass-additional-parameters-to-the-insert-update-delete-sps-that-are-mapped)
The answer for the above topic would satisfy my scenario, as well.